# Insert ajax populated dropdown into database in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<select id="country" name="country" onChange="getState(this.value)" class="dropdown">
<option value="0">Select Country</option>
<?php 
echo $country;
?>
</select>
```

the above code takes country from database, according to the country using ajax, i have created one dropdown using below code, am not able to insert the state value. how can I get the state value in php dbpage for inserting the state valu

```
<div id="statediv" >
<select id="ddlstate" name="ddlstate"  class="dropdown" value="0">
<option>Select Country First</option>
</select>
</div>
this is my full ajax code
function getState(countryId)
{       
    var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {                        
                document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                     
            }
            else {
                alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
            }
        }
    }           
    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
    req.send(null);
    }
}
```

this is findState.php

```
<?php $country=intval($_GET['country']);
    $query="SELECT stateid,statename FROM state WHERE countryid='$country'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="state" onchange="getCity(<?php echo $country?>,this.value)">
    <option>Select State</option>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row['stateid']?>>
            <?php echo $row['statename']?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Show your PHP code also

Comment: $state_id=$_POST['ddlstate']; i am getting the value like this in my php db page ,, this is my insert query insert into query_mas(employee_id,country_id,state_id,city_id,experience,query) values('".$employee_id."','".$country_id."','".$state_id."','".$city_id."','".$experience."')";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your Ajax is generating and populating the drop down properly, like so:

```
<select id="country" name="country" onChange="getState(this.value)" class="dropdown">
<option value="0">Select Country</option>
<option value="1">Country1</option>
<option value="2">Country2</option>
<option value="3">Country3</option>
</select>
```

Check with firebug, or by viewing the source code of the page. Once you know thats correct, submit the form and use PHP code like this to check:

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['country'] ) ) {
 echo $_REQUEST['country'];
} else {
 echo "Country not sent from form";
}
```

Once you know the country is being sent from your form, you can use the value to put into a database or whatever you like.

Comment: am getting country value easily, no issues with that countryid, The problem is I need to get state id from ajax dropdown value

Comment: this is my error                                                  insert into query_mas(employee_id,country_id,state_id,city_id,experience,query) values('4','4','','','17')                                             Am not able to insert the stateid in my db page

Comment: Can you update your question with more code. It would help if you can show the getState() function. And the PHP code that deals with the Ajax request.

Comment: here you see,I actually want stateid value in a different page(ie my db page),

Comment: What does your Ajax call return? What does the HTML for the <div id="statediv" > look like after the Ajax call? View the page source and see if its correct. And also, put code in your original post by editing it, instead of in the comments, Its hard to read.

Comment: I see what your problem is, I have a feeling the dropdown is not being populated properly. What does the Ajax call return?

Comment: ajax call is returning the state id value according to the countryid, if you are not getting, pls feel free to ask :), I had added the javascript function in the question

Comment: I dont think you understand what I am asking you. I know it is supposed to return the stateid's, but what is the actual code the ajax call returns? is it HTML code? is it json? is it XML? can you show me an example?

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and put the PHP code that deals with the Ajax there. I think there is a problem with that code, but I cannot tell you what it is until I see it.

Comment: Husman am really sorry for wasting your valuable time,I had added tat php code now, please check it

Comment: Yes I got the answer, THANKS HUSMAN, I can get the state id from the findstate.php and I called tat in my db page, that was a small error with id problem , thanks once again

Comment: Just as I thought, your PHP code is creating a select called <select name="state" onchange="getCity(<?php echo $country?>,this.value)">, the one on your page is called 'ddlstate'

Answer (score 0):

please find the states using countryid  and execute in such a manner.

```
<?php $states= getStates($countryid);
$str ='';
$str .='<select id="ddlstate" name="ddlstate"  class="dropdown" value="0">';
foreach($states as $val){
$str.='<option value="'.$val->id.'">'.$val->name.'</option>';
}
$str.='</select>';
echo $str; exit; ?>
```

This is just sample code  which you need to use in php file

Comment: thank you for answering, but am already able to populate dropdown for state using countryid, I just want to insert the stateid in my db page. I think you are not getting my question

Answer (score 0):

I guess your insert into query is wrong. Check the number of fields and the values provided.

```
insert into query_mas(employee_id,country_id,state_id,city_id,experience,query) values('".$employee_id."','".$country_id."','".$state_id."','".$city_id."','".$e‌​xperience."')";
```

Comment: this is the insert query GBR
insert into query_mas(employee_id,country_id,state_id,city_id,experience,query) values('".$employee_id."','".$country_id."','".$state_id."','".$city_id."','".$experience."','".$query."').. THANKS GBR, I already got the answer, thanks once again

Comment: @Sam so what was the actual problem..?? are you now able to insert the state id into the db?

Comment: earler I was not able to get the stateid from the dropdown, now using the stateid value from my ajax page, am able to get the stateid, Now am able to insert state id into the DB, thank you GBROcks :)